# The install-plugin command is deprecated in Grails

Tags: grails, plugins, groovy

i am new in grails..i try to install plugin using the command  "install-plugin easygrid:1.5.0" in run. i got the warning as follow

"| Warning The install-plugin command is deprecated and may be removed from a future version of Grails.  Plugin dependencies should be expressed in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy.  See http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/conf.html#pluginDependencies.
| Resolving plugin easygrid:1.5.0. Please wait...
| Error resolving plugin [name:1.5.0, group:easygrid, version:latest.integration]. Plugin not found.
| Error Plugin not found for name [easygrid:1.5.0] and version [not specified]"

how to install-plugins in run or using BuildConfig.grooovy in grails?

thanks in advance

Comment: It's not just deprecated - it's gone in recent versions. But this is all very clearly described in the fine manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the *Dependency* section on the Grails' plugin page, it should be located near the top of the page right under the author & licence sections. Copy the text from there into your `BuildConfig.groovy` file into the `plugins` block and (re)start Grails.

Your BuildConfig could look like this:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"

//..some other configuration


grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

//..some other configuration and blocks

    plugins {
        //.. other plugins
        compile ":easygrid:1.6.9"
    }
}
```

Comment: restart grails is enough for installing the plugin? how to find that plugin is installed or not?

Comment: Restart is enough, you should see messages in the console about the plugin being installed when Grails are starting up. You can use the `grails list-plugins -installed` command to see a list of all your installed plugins.

Comment: | Loading Grails 2.2.0
| Configuring classpath
| Downloading: grails-easygrid-1.6.9.zip.sha1
| Downloading: xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar.sha1
| Downloading: grails-jquery-1.11.1.zip.sha1
| Downloading: grails-easygrid-1.6.9.zip.sha1
| Downloading: log4j-1.2.14.pom.sha1
| Downloading: grails-easygrid-1.6.9.zip.sha1
| Downloading: log4j-1.2.14.jar.sha1
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:easygrid:1.6.9.

Comment: Try putting `log("warn")` into your `grails.project.dependency.resolution` closure.